# What does a space preceding :nth-child(n) do?

Tags: css, css-selectors

While I was writing a bit of CSS, a situation that I have never encountered before using the `:nth-child(n)` appeared and I was doubt of what is actually happening.

When I use pseudo classes, I write them without a space between the selector, like so:

```css
div#wrap:hover {
    border-bottom: 2px solid orange;
}
/* OR */
div#wrap:nth-child(4) {
    border-bottom: 2px solid orange;
}
```

But it didn't work the way I expected, so I tried inserting a space between the selector and the pseudo class. Surprisingly, it worked:

```css
div#wrap :nth-child(4) {
    border-bottom: 2px solid orange;
}
```

What is happening to make this work?

```css
div#wrap :nth-child(4) {
  border-bottom: 2px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <h1>Heading 1</h1>
  <p>This is a test!</p>
  <h2>Creating content</h2>
  <p>The next paragraph uses the <strong>.html</strong> method to create a new element.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Consider this: if `div#wrap:hover` refers to `div#wrap` while *it* is hovered, then you would not expect the meaning of the selector to change dramatically simply by swapping out `:hover` for `:nth-child()` without making any other changes to the selector. To wit, `div#wrap:nth-child(4)` means `div#wrap` when *it* is the 4th child element.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the selector. It selects the element that is also the `:nth-child(n)` which *also has* the preceding element as a parent.

When there is no selector preceding, it defaults to `*:nth-child(n)`

Because you probably only want to apply this to direct descendants and not every element which is the fourth child of its parent and a descendant of the parent, I would use `.element > *:nth-child(n)` to only apply to direct descendants.

```css
div#wrap > *:nth-child(4) {
  border-bottom: 2px solid orange;
}
```

```css
div#wrap > *:nth-child(4) {
  border-bottom: 2px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <h1>Heading 1</h1>
  <p>This is a test!</p>
  <h2>Creating content</h2>
  <p>The next paragraph uses the <strong>.html</strong> method to create a new element.</p>
</div>
```

If you wanted to be more specific and only select the fourth child if it is a `<p>` element, you can use `.element > p:nth-child(n)`. This will select all `<p>` elements that are the fourth direct descendant of elements matching the `div#wrap` selector.

```css
div#wrap > p:nth-child(4) {
  border-bottom: 2px solid orange;
}
```

```css
div#wrap > p:nth-child(4) {
  border-bottom: 2px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <h1>Heading 1</h1>
  <p>This is a test!</p>
  <h2>Creating content</h2>
  <p>The next paragraph uses the <strong>.html</strong> method to create a new element.</p>
</div>
```

If you want to select the second `<p>` element directly descending from each `div#wrap`, you can use `.element > p:nth-of-type(n)` like so:

```css
div#wrap > p:nth-of-type(2) {
  border-bottom: 2px solid orange;
}
```

```css
div#wrap > p:nth-of-type(2) {
  border-bottom: 2px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <h1>Heading 1</h1>
  <p>This is a test!</p>
  <h2>Creating content</h2>
  <p>The next paragraph uses the <strong>.html</strong> method to create a new element.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

**What does the space do?**

Space before `:nth-child(4)` is equal to `*:nth-child(4)`. `*` is a global CSS selector. So if ***any*** child element which is 4th in the list of elements of ***any*** parent, the CSS rules are applied to that element.

But using `#wrap` before the `nth-child` will limit the scope of the selection within the `#wrap` element.

**Alternate Solution(Understanding how nth-child works):**

You can also use: `p:nth-child(4)` which targets the paragraph element which is 4th with respect to the parent element which is `#wrap`.

`:nth-child` will select irrespective of whatever the element is, or what the sibling elements are. You will need to use `:nth-of-type` to differentiate.

```css
* {
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
p:nth-child(4) {
  border-bottom: 2px solid orange;
}
p:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: lightblue;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <h1>Heading 1</h1>
  <p>This is a test!</p>
  <h2>Creating content</h2>
  <p>The next paragraph uses the <strong>.html</strong> method to create a new element.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Right, however how come 'p:nth-child(4)' works in this case? Doesn't that mean that its selecting the 4th paragraph tag? (which does not exist)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: No `:nth-child` will select irrespective of what the element is, or what the sibling elements are. You will need to use `nth-of-type` to differentiate. Check my updated code.

Comment: Now I get it! Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

A space in a CSS selector means the next part is a descendant (not direct descendant) of what was previously selected.

`tr td` means a `<td>` inside a `<tr>`.
`table td` means a `<td>` inside a `<table>`.

In your case, the `:nth-child()` pseudo-class is applied after the `<div>` so it matches for the nth (4th...) child of that div. Had you removed the space, it would match a the 4th div with id "wrap" (which doesn't exist)